# When did user accounts using UIDs above 1000 become normal? And why?

Tags: nis, uid, conventions

We have a really old NIS domain which is mapping some user accounts to UIDs less than 1000. I'm wondering

- when did using UIDs greater than or equal to 1000 for human users become 'standard',
- why did it become a convention? Are there any practical implications or reasons for this? (i.e. anything similar like the 'convention' of trusting ports below 1000)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359006/173368

Answer (score 3):

According the [UNIX and Linux System Administration Handbook (5th Edition)](https://www.admin.com) the idea behind starting UIDs at 1000 is to provide plenty of room for nonhuman users that might get added in the future.